# Why can't I access included function?

Tags: c, include, clion

I don't succeed to access included function:

`LineParser.h`:

```
typedef struct cmdLine
{
    char * const arguments[MAX_ARGUMENTS]; 
    int argCount;   
    char const *inputRedirect;  
    char const *outputRedirect;
    char blocking;  
    int idx;    
    struct cmdLine *next;   
} cmdLine;

cmdLine *parseCmdLines(const char *strLine);
```

and `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "LineParser.h"
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char cwd[256];
    char input[2048];
    fgets(input, 2048, stdin);
    cmdLine * parsedCLines= parseCmdLines(input);


    return 0;
}
```

When trying to build it via linux terminal it doesn't succeed and I get :

```
undefined reference to `parseCmdLines' 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:5: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: What is that stray `}` in your code?

Comment: Can you spot me please?

Comment: In `main`, before `return 0;`

Comment: This is a mistake.

Comment: @tkausl I don't understand why is it duplicate. Can you please spot me where is the answer? Thanks

Comment: You should show us [mcve] - including the function definition if there is one - and the command you are using to compile your code.

Comment: To be clear you have not included a function, you have only  included a function declaration.

Comment: The thing is, that the exact same program runs on clion but not on linux terminal, that's why I didn't supply the external function. Maybe the problem is with the makefile

Comment: How are you building your application? Do you have any includes in LineParser.c?

Comment: No, I dont have any includes in LineParser.c. I build it by accessing the directory which contains LineParser.h, LineParser.c, main.c and the makefile, then I run the command `make`.

Comment: What does the actual build command in the Makefile look like?  It sounds like either `LineParser.c` isn't being built, or the resulting object file isn't being linked into the final program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply an implementation of parseCmdLines along with a prototype (either in main.c, but preferably in a separate file).

Comment: This function is supplied and is working ok.